# Yii2: How to execute sql query after model->save()

Tags: php, mysql, yii, yii2

```
    public function actionCreate()
        {
            $model = new CreateBookings();

            if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
                $imageName = $model->first_name;
                $mobile    = $model->primary_mobile;
                $type      = $model->room_type;

                $model->file = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'file');
                $model->file->saveAs('uploads/id_images/' . $imageName . '_' . $mobile . '.' . $model->file->extension);
                //save the path in the db column
                $model->id_image = 'uploads/id_images/' . $imageName . '_' . $mobile . '.' . $model->file->extension;
                $model->save();



                return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
            } else {
                return $this->render('create', [
                    'model' => $model,
                ]);
            }

        }
```

I need to execute query `\Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE room_types SET total_booked = total_booked + 1 WHERE room_type = '$model->room_type' ")->execute();` after the model->save();

same query working in actionupdate() but not in actioncreate(),
Is it possible with behaviours?

Answer (score 1):

You could override `afterSave` method of ActiveRecord or create a trigger directly on db

Documentation: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#afterSave%28%29-detail

```
public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
{
    parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);

    // your code here
    Yii::$app->db->createCommand(sprintf("UPDATE room_types SET total_booked = total_booked + 1 WHERE room_type = '%s'", $this->room_type))->execute();

}
```

Comment: can you please show how to override `afterSave` method?

Comment: rename changeAttributes in changedAttributes

Comment: `public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes)
    {
        
        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);

        \Yii::$app->db->createCommand("UPDATE room_types SET total_booked = total_booked + 1 WHERE room_type = '$model->room_type' ")->execute();
    }` I have place this in model

Comment: still not updating the values in database